# How to dynamically set layout parameters in Android?

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, parameters, android-edittext

I have these text fields which I generated dynamically. But I can't seem to set layout parameters for them. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I'm able to generate the fields without layout parameters. However, If I use `LayoutParams`, it doesn't even get generated.

Code:

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);

TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams trparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tr.setLayoutParams(trparams);

cg[i] = new EditText(this);
weight[i] = new EditText(this);
cg[i].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
weight[i].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

//Here's where it goes wrong. By adding fieldparams, the text field doesn't even get generated.
LinearLayout.LayoutParams fieldparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
tr.addView(cg[i], fieldparams);
tr.addView(weight[i], fieldparams);

table.addView(tr);
```

Comment: Y r u using linearlayout.layoutparams on a tablerow? It shud be tablerow.layoutparams

Comment: Nice comment...butlittle correction Amit.it will be TableLayout not TableRow

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are adding Table Row into table so use `TableLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.As we use LayoutParam according to parent in which we are going to add

Answer (score 6):

You have to use **TableRow.LayoutParams** instead of **LinearLayout.LayoutParams**

Replace your code

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams fieldparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
```

with the below code.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams fieldparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(10, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
```

Its working fine. Let me know what happened. :-)